# AttributeError when trying to use _set in django form (for filter_horizontal widget)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm just trying to configure a filter_horizontal widget for one of the fields on the admin form for a model. but I get the following error when I try to use _set to reverse an m2m relationship.

The model I'm creating a form for is called `Statement`. And I'm trying to work with a field it has calls `keywords`, which draws an m2m with another model.

```
class Statement(models.Model):
   statement_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   issue_date = models.DateField("Issue-Date")
   author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
   released_by = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
   keywords = models.ManyToManyField('KeywordInContext')
```

So in the form I try to configure the filter_horizontal widget, but I get an attribute error when I try to use `keywords_set`.

```
class StatementForm(forms.ModelForm):
 statement_keywords = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=KeywordInContext.objects.all(),
    required=False,
    label=('Select keywords that you would like to assign to this statement on the left. Keywords that are assigned to this statement are on the right.'),
    widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
        verbose_name='Keywords Associated with Statement',
        is_stacked=False
      )
)
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StatementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.pk:
       self.fields['statement_keywords'].initial = self.instance.keywords_set.all() ##CAUSES ATTRIBUTE ERROR

def save(self, commit=True):
    statement = super(StatementForm, self).save(commit=False)
    if commit:
        statement.save()
    if statement.pk:
        statement.keywords_set = self.cleaned_data['keywords'] #change to keyword if need be
        self.save_m2m()

    return statement
```

The error message I get is

```
 File "./gtr_site/forms.py", line 73, in __init__
     self.fields['statement_keywords'].initial = self.instance.keywords_set.all()
      AttributeError: 'Statement' object has no attribute 'keywords_set'
```

What confuses me the most is the fact that this error message recognizes the Statement object but offers that I'm to accessing the "keywords_set" attribute (an attempt to reverse the m2m relationship) is incorrect.

What is the issue? It may be a minor syntactical one but this is how I thought I'd be able to reverse the m2m relationship of the **keywords** field this way.

Answer (score 1):

You have the ManyToMany relationship on Statement, to access to this relation is throw keywords not keywords_set

```
 statement.keywords.all()
```

To access to this relation on the KeywordInContext Model is throw statement_set

```
KeywordInContext.statement_set.all()
```